# In SwiftUI, how do you get a view to take as much space as possible?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to get views to take up as much room/space as possible based on the minimum requirements of other views in the layout, but I can't seem to get the exact result I want.

Consider this code...

```swift
struct MainView: View {

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            Color.red

            HStack {
                Color.green
                Color.blue
                    .frame(maxWidth: 100)
            }
            .frame(maxHeight: 100)
        }
        .padding()

    }
}
```

This produces the following output.  However, this is only because `HStack` and `Blue` have their `maxHeight` and `maxWidth` values set respectively.

[image: Example]

What I'm trying to do is have the opposite... I want the **minimum** size of `blue` to dictate the size of the others.

In this example, I want `green` to push `blue` as far to the right as it can until `blue` says 'I'm as small as I can be!' and then have green fill the rest horizontally.

Likewise, I want `red` to push the `HStack` down as far as it can go until the `HStack` says 'I can't get any shorter (also because of `blue`) and have red fill in the rest of the vertical space.

Now from the documentation, I *thought* it stated if you specify `red.frame(maxHeight: .infinity)` and `green.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)`, it should work, but they seem to have no effect at all, let alone giving me the desired result.

```swift
struct MainView: View {

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            Color.red
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)

            HStack {

                Color.green
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

                Color.blue
                    .frame(minWidth: 100, minHeight: 100)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

That code produces this...

[image]

So what am I missing? How can I let the minimum size of `blue` dictate the rest of the layout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`layoutPriority`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/layoutpriority(_:)) modifier with a value larger than zero to tell SwiftUI you want `Color.red` and `Color.green` to get as much space as possible. From the documentation:

> Views typically have a default priority of 0 which causes space to be apportioned evenly to all sibling views. Raising a view’s layout priority encourages the higher priority view to shrink later when the group is shrunk and stretch sooner when the group is stretched.

Here's your second attempt, with `layoutPriority(1)` attached to `Color.red` and `Color.green`:

```
struct MainView: View {

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            Color.red
                .layoutPriority(1)

            HStack {

                Color.green
                    .layoutPriority(1)

                Color.blue
                    .frame(minWidth: 100, minHeight: 100)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: Demo image showing the results of the above with red pushing down until blue's min height, and green pushing right until blue's min width]

Comment: Perfect!  When using this, you don't need the frame modifier at all!